# CSS How to make div be always on top

Tags: css

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vbxh0mr5/1/):

I want to make `div #b` always be full-visible, if the scroll of inner div is on top, `#b` must be shown out of `#a` and cover the `#c`

Comment: Can you please reword your question? It seems that #b shouldn't be nested in #a, but I'm not sure I'm understanding your question 100%

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this is what you want. Try it in the fiddle you have created.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="m">
     <div id="b">b</div>
    <div id="a">a

    </div>

</div> 
<div id="c">c</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#b {

    position:absolute;
    background: blue;
    width: 20px;
    height: 70px;
}
```

Comment: It makes effect like position: fixed that's not what I wanted. I need #b to be scrolled with #a.

Comment: Can you add an image of the effect you are trying to achieve? Not able to understand the requirement clearly,Sorry!!

Comment: I want #b (its bootstrap dropdown) to act like html select: positioned in #a and scrolling with it, but when "opened" must stay visible in "top layer of the page ~ like z-index 9999"